# Back button creating multiple components on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular6

> In my Angular 6 app, there are certain pages that do not respond
>   appropriately when I click "back". The site will instead spawn
>   multiple components, instead of redirecting the user back to the
>   single component they just went to.
>
> For the faulty components, I made the component.html page be one
>   single line like such as:
>
> `// home-page.component.html 
>   home`
>
> and
>
> `// admin-page.component.html 
>   admin`
>
> And then the component.ts page is using default code as well.
>
> On my app.component.html, I just have the following:
>
> `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
>
> Now when I go on the home page (via `<a
>   routerLink="/admin">Admin></a>`), I correctly see this (more or
>   less)in my HTML when I inspect the site. And note this is just the RESULTING HTML that appears when I right click - view page source etc... I know my routing is setup correctly as this whole thing works in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox.
>
> `<html>
>       <head>...</head>
>       <body>
>           <app-root>
>               <router-outlet>
>                   <app-admin-page>admin</app-admin-page>
>               </router-outlet>
>           </app-root>
>       </body> </html>`
>
> But when I now press "back", I see the below
>
> `<html>
>       <head>...</head>
>       <body>
>           <app-root>
>               <router-outlet>
>                   <app-home-page>home</app-home-page>
>                   <app-admin-page>admin</app-admin-page>
>               </router-outlet>
>           </app-root>
>       </body> </html>`
>
> When I pressed "back", it should of DELETED the
>   `<app-admin-page>admin</app-admin-page>` and just kept the new
>   `<app-home-page>home</app-home-page>`, but it keeps both. I can then
>   press "forward" and then it'll have 3 components. Any ideas what is
>   going on here? Note that if I'm on the 'admin' page and click the 'home'  link (which does a routerLink thing), it works correctly. It's just the back button messing up.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem. Using 'back buttons' on the UI I created work fine, however my angular app is wrapped in Cordova and lives on an Android device. When a user uses the native android back button, I see multiple components stacked on one another. How were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I don't remember sorry - I stopped on the app soon after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing child components and routing. For any particular component, you should use one or the other.

There should be no components defined between the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tags.

Notice in your code above:

```
          <router-outlet>
              <app-admin-page>admin</app-admin-page>
          </router-outlet>
```

So either display both components as child components like this:

```
      <app-root>
         <app-home-page>home</app-home-page>
         <app-admin-page>admin</app-admin-page>
      </app-root>
```

This will show both components, one above the other.

OR

Use routing:

```
      <app-root>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </app-root>
```

This will show one component at a time in this location. Use a route configuration to define which components to display in the router outlet.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent }
]),
```

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong and I'll edit .... but I AM using the routing that you described up above. These components are not children of each other, and are completely separate pages. Additionally --- this entire site works just fine in Google Chrome, but messes up once i start using Firefox. So I know I'm coding in most everything correctly, but there is just some issue I'm not seeing that makes it messed up in Firefox.

Comment: If you have tags between your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tags, consider removing them ... even if it does appear to work.

Comment: there's no tags at all there, my app.component.html is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where under certain circumstances when I hit the "Back" button in the browser, it would combine the current component with the one defined for the updated URL hash. I was able to resolve it by adding this in my constructor of each component:

```
      constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router, private location: PlatformLocation, private network: NetworkService) {
    location.onPopState(() => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(location.hash.replace('#/', ''))).then();
    });
  }
```

It then properly navigated to a preceding component without combining both on the page.